# Modifying the scroll view function scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I wanted to override the function `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation` for a reference to a `tableView` within a class.

In other words, I have a view and a `UITableView` within it, I dragged a reference to the table into the view controller and want to change the `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation` for the same, is it possible to do so?

I have looked at previous responses to similar questions and they ask suggest making the class a `scrollViewDelegate` and implementing the function, but I have done so and it doesn't hit the breakpoint I have within the function even if I scroll through the table in the Simulator.

Answer (score 0):

This method only gets called if the `setContentOffset:animated:` or `scrollRectToVisible:animated:` methods are called by you on the scrollView, and only if the animated parameter is set to true.

Scrolling the view in the simulator will not trigger the breakpoint in your implementation, but using either of those two methods will.

[UIScrollViewDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios//documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:)